# How to get value of Tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to adapt the example of creating GAN using TensorFlow in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan

I would be interested how the loss functions of generator and discriminator behave during training.

However if I do something along the lines

```
@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([BATCH_SIZE, noise_dim])
    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
      generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
      real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
      fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
      gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
      disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)
    print("Type of gen_loss is %s"%(type(gen_loss))) #tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'
    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)
    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
    return np.array([gen_loss.eval(), disc_loss.eval()])

def train(dataset, epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        start = time.time()
        allloss = np.zeros(shape=(0,2))
        for image_batch in dataset:
            loss = train_step(image_batch)
            allloss = np.vstack((allloss, loss))
        # Produce images for the GIF as you go
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        generate_and_save_images(generator,
                                 epoch + 1,
                                 seed)
        # Save the model every 15 epochs
        if (epoch + 1) % 15 == 0:
          checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
        loss = np.mean(allloss, axis=0)
        print ('Time for epoch {} is {} sec generator {} discriminator {}'.format(epoch + 1, time.time()-start, loss[0], loss[1]))
    # Generate after the final epoch
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    generate_and_save_images(generator,
                             epochs,
                             seed)
```

I get error  `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using eval(): No default session is registered. Use with sess.as_default() or pass an explicit session to eval(session=sess)` and when I do not use eval, I am getting error that is not possible to convert Tensor to numpy object.

Even if Tensor is somehow evaluated in a lazy way, its value is needed when executing calls to these `disc_tape.gradient` type functions so that it shall be available within `train_step` function and I don't see a reason why there shall be no way returning it out of the function regardless the session. And if the session needs to be provided to read the value why it does not be provided to execute `train_step` function?

Comment: Interestingly `return [gen_loss, disc_loss]` did the trick.